# Close an external window from inside only using drywall

Tags: drywall, windows, mold

In our bedroom, we have 4 square picture windows (they don't open. Size 23*23 inches). We want to close 2 of them and make it a tv wall. So idea is to, fill the space with insulation , frame it from inside, drywall it and paint it to blend it with existing wall.

What risks are involved to do that? Someone told us it can lead to molds from moisture retaining from the outside glass. Is there a way to avoid that or should we entirely drop this idea?

Any help is appreciated :)

Link to the windows:
https://imgur.com/a/SGN7wfX

Closer look :
https://imgur.com/a/LJjJyOX

We have temporarily covered them with random paintings.

Comment: If you are going to do all that work, why are you not removing the window frame (and glass) and covering the exterior properly?

Comment: Listen to the "someone" .   What you are proposing is a bad idea.

Comment: What's it look like from the *outside?*

Comment: All of that sounds like too much work and unnecessarily permanent. Card board cut to fit. Window treatment to hide it. - TV is already hung. If there were two more windows behind it and no how-to hang it, then yeah. I'd still leave the two on the sides 'operable' for day light when you want it: I lived with 9' tall windows trying to use a projector during the day. They appropriately called us vampires; I did paint the cardboard black so it didn't totally look like crap. Paint and put some drywall facing out first, if you're doing this.